# ListFragment Layout from xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

How to create a **ListFragment** (of the support v4 library) **layout** from xml?
`ListFragment` sets up its layout programmatically, so if you want to modify it, you need to mess with add/remove view.

Comment: Please edit this so it's clear what the problem was (post it as a question) and put the solution below in the answers section.

Comment: do you have an example to refer?

Comment: The post should just be in the form of a question and an answer.  This looks like a solution, but it's not clear what the original question was that it answers.

Comment: yes you are right, I was asking for an example post, or it's enough to move the body in an answer and add the question?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I've converted the created layout to xml, you can add/remove your widgets or e.g. add `pulltorefresh` solutions. You shouldn't change the needed ids.
Because of internal ids needed for some of the widgets an helper function needs to be called and it needs to be in support v4 namespace since constants are internal with default visibility.

`list_loader.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and the class `ListFragmentLayout` in `android.support.v4.app` (in your project, you don't need to modify support v4 jar)

```
package android.support.v4.app;

import your.package.R;
import android.view.View;

public class ListFragmentLayout
{
    public static void setupIds(View view)
    {
        view.findViewById(R.id.empty_id).setId(ListFragment.INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID);
        view.findViewById(R.id.progress_container_id).setId(ListFragment.INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);
        view.findViewById(R.id.list_container_id).setId(ListFragment.INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID);
    }
}
```

in your fragment that extends `ListFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_loader, container, false);
    ListFragmentLayout.setupIds(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: you mean with this changes it will work as if it's not a custom view?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Looks like i'm using older revision of the support lib. It doesn't even contain ListFragmentLayout class. I don't suggest using this approach. In future revisions of support lib it might not work.

Comment: @sherpya, I followed your answer and got `The field ListFragment.INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID is not visible` error

Comment: you have to put the code in the package android.support.v4.app because the field has default visibility

Comment: perhaps you can still pick the values from the *corresponding* source, in r12 they are:
    static final int INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID = 0x00ff0001;
    static final int INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0002;
    static final int INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0003;

Comment: Hi @sherpya, thanks for the soultion :) But I'm not able to use a button in my layout as onClickListener doesn't work. Do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: did you tried `view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton).setOnClieckListener()` before `return view`?

Answer (score -2):

From the android sdk (ListFragment) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html):

> *public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)*
>
> Provide default implementation to return a simple list view. Subclasses can override to replace with their own layout. If doing so, the returned view hierarchy must have a ListView whose id is android.R.id.list and can optionally have a sibling view id android.R.id.empty that is to be shown when the list is empty.
>
> If you are overriding this method with your own custom content, consider including the standard layout list_content in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard behavior of ListFragment. In particular, this is currently the only way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.

So when you want your own layout.xml for a FragmentList overide onCreateView and inflate your own layout.

For example:

Create a android layout (*yourlistlayout.xml*) and put the following xml on the position where you want to show your ListFragment.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
```

in your *ListFragment* class put the following code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlistlayout, null);       
    return v;       
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work with support library since ids are different