# Inflate view in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment Activity in my application, in which, i don´t override the oncreateview. I would like to inflate a View from xml the first time that list is shown. At the moment I am trying to inflate it on the onActivityCreated method, and using:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view,null);
```

What is the correct approach to do this?

Comment: what's wrong with onCreateView?

Comment: you may be interested in my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770773/listfragment-layout-from-xml

Comment: currently im not inflating anything in the onCreateView,but when I do try, I have some errrors concerning to things that I have on the onActivityCreated such as setEmptyText, setHasOptionsMenu and getListView

Comment: Fragment lifecycles are a bit tricky.  You really should inflate in onCreateView, and then address the other problems.  Post your errors and perhaps we can help.