# ListFragment or ListView preview in Layout Editor

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor

I'm trying to preview a `ListFragment` in the Graphical Layout Editor. As it has no fragment layout to preview, I simply created an xml with a `ListView` inside, just to see how the items look, and set *Preview List Content* with one of the default item layouts, just to try.

The problems are:

1. <strike>The list in the preview is empty, no matter what *Preview List Content* I choose;</strike> (I don't know what I was doing wrong, now it works)
2. I want to preview my own custom list item *View*, not just a layout, because I'll be doing few things when `isInEditMode()` is true.

Any idea?

**EDIT**: The fragment is a `ListFragment`, but I can live with using a "temporary" listview.xml layout. What I want is a way to see a listview with my `CustomListItemView` inside. In the fragment, I'll place them there with a custom adapter; in the layout editor I wish I could choose `CustomListItemView` from *Preview List Content* menu.

I can't just use the custom item's layout as Preview List Content, because its root is a `<merge>` (my custom item extends `RelativeLayout`). This could be solved by changing for a moment `<merge>` into `<RelativeLayout>`. However, this custom item view changes depending on data, so I'd love to see a preview of the various states, by using the `isInEditMode()` facility.

The best would be if it all could work without the temporary listview.xml layout, but this is becoming a feature request.

Right now I'm resorting to use a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Comment: So you have a layout, which includes a tag, and the Fragment contains a ListView, and each list item should be using a custom list item layout, and the list item layout uses your own custom view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look, and it looks like the answer is that this isn't possible today, because of two bugs.

1. For some reason, ListView preview doesn't work if the ListView is the root element of the layout, rather than being embedded within the layout. The workaround for this is simple; just surround the ListView with some other layout such as a LinearLayout, setting you ListView's layout_width and layout_height to match_parent.
2. For some reason, when a layout with a ListView along with a custom view is included into another layout, the custom list item layout isn't working. I know this used to work, so it must have broken at some point, probably when we switched from using comment-style metadata to the tools-namespace metadata to record which layout to use.

I've filed this issue to track the work:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36838

Comment: (1) surely explains why it "started working". So, should it be possible, at least theoretically, to do something like `tools:listitem="com.example.my.CustomItemView" `? Or it accepts only layouts?

Comment: It only accepts layouts. See line 63 of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/1413cae86a54c8644bda5e96737b0b43f9624259/layoutlib_api/src/com/android/ide/common/rendering/api/DataBindingItem.java .

Answer (score 1):

you can find useful my post about using a layout for a listfragment, it will not solve all of your problems but at least you can work directly with the effective layout you are going to use:

[ListFragment Layout from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770773/listfragment-layout-from-xml)