# Android Studio layout previews for Listview + Gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview, android-studio

Is there a way to get Android Studio's layout preview screen to populate a GridView or ListView with placeholder views of the actual runtime layout?

In other words, I don't want to see a grid of "Item 1/ Sub Item 1" views, I want to be able to set @layout/foo somewhere and have it show up in there.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From graphical editor:

[image: Adding list item preview]

From xml:

```
<GridView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item"/>
```

Note: pay attention to this isse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188118/624706

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if there is a similar function for spinners (since they appear to be similar in implementation to ListView, though the right-click context menu does not appear to contain the same option)?

edit: Nevermind, the XML works for Spinners as well, I just made a typo when I tried it out. Thanks again!

Comment: on my version, I don't have a context menu, and this functionality requires `android:id` to be set