# Android Studio Preview Window - Render ListView Item Template

Tags: android-listview, android-studio

In Android Studio, while working in Text mode for a view i have the "Preview" window active to the right. When adding a listview to the view it renders a default list. I have a custom template which is used at runtime but is it possible to have the preview window show me my template at design time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the tools namespace to your xml layout:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

next you can specify the listitem layout like this:

```
tools:listitem="@layout/mycustom_listitem"
```

Full example:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lv_contactslist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/listitem_contact" />
```

For a graphical way, have a look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858846/2771851)