# Navigation drawer with Activity and child Fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have a **Activity** `A`, a **ListFragment** `P` and **2 Fragments** `Q` and `R`.

When the app is launched, `A` is created, which loads `P`. Based on what user clicks,  it is replaced by `Q` or `R`.

Now by referencing [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) tutorial, I have implemented a **Navigation Drawer** which shows certain items to the user. However, since I have implemented the Navigation Drawer in the Activity, it shows for all the Fragments. 
I want it to be only available to `P`.

(Very much similar to Googles Gmail app. When the user is on the main screen - the drawer is present. When user taps to open an email, the drawer changes to back button)

I am not sure how to translate the above code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it's not another activity? I think you can anyway make a framelayout as the activity layout and then replace the drawerfragment at all

Comment: If you mean implement the drawer as a fragment and replace it, then that is an interesting suggestion that I did not think of. Will try and get back to you!

Comment: `DrawerLayout` is a `Layout` I think you can just inflate it into a fragment

Comment: Well, I am using a list fragment which uses the default android list layout. But I will try with a custom layout. Though for the drawer, I am guessing that I will still need the activity context. So not sure how it can be specific to that fragment.

Comment: if you need to customize `ListFragment` layout you can follow my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770773/listfragment-layout-from-xml/12145683#12145683

Comment: @sherpya, the solution to this was really simple :) I have added my answer if you are curious!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue by simply overriding the up carat behavior by calling the `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(enable)` and passing the **boolean** `enable` or `disable` as needed.

(The fragments where I didn't want the drawer to show called this method with **false** and where I wanted the drawer to be shown called this method with **true**. I put the call inside the `onResume()` of the respective fragment for obvious reasons.)

This works exactly like I want, and I did not have to change the design of my project :).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a new `FragmanetActivity` `S` and replace `Q` and `R` accordingly. If you are app is for Android 3.0 lower user `ActionBarActivity` create a `actionbar` and set its `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. As the new `FragmentActivity` will have new layout there will be no `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: This is the obvious solution, yes. But I want to see if there is a way of doing it using just Fragments, and avoid introducing unnecessary Activities. :)

Comment: @rgamber AFAIK I don't think its possible as the main `layout` remains same when `Fragment` is replace in the `FrameLayout`. Just the contents of the `FrameLayout` are changing whenever a `Fragment` is replaced and `NavigationDrawer` is attached to the main layout so it will always be above the `FrameLayout`.