# How do I refer to two listviews in the same layout with @android:id/list?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-listfragment

I am trying to set two different adapters on two listviews in the same layout. After a few searches on the internet and this error "must have a listview whos id must be android.R.id.list", I have found out I need to define my listview id as @android:id/list.

What I wonder is how do I refer to two different listviews that are using @android:id/list?

Does the following code make sense?

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

ps: I am working in a Fragment and extending ListFragment.

Comment: give different id in xml file

Comment: You must have to use custom adapter for that. In this case you no need to use this id, and can change name with any thing. But the question is, why you need it?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770773/listfragment-layout-from-xml

Comment: You have to define two difference id for two ListView and also check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list

Comment: why do you have two different ListView in the same fragment ?

Comment: I am using two different adapters, but that's not the problem. I was wondering if with that code I was referring to the same listview, instead of the twos? In other words, how does android know that lv1 is different from lv2?

Comment: @blackbelt I need a listview, some text and then another listview to show other "stuff".

Comment: can't you have two different Fragment with one ListView?

Comment: @blackbelt I didn't think about that, can't I just use two listviews in the same fragment?

Comment: `I am working in a Fragment and extending ListFragment.` THIS is the problem. You better extend Fragment (containing two ListViews, with different ids), instead of ListFragment. **OR** use 2 different ListFragments, each containing its own ListView. As you know, an Activity can contain multiple Fragments (or derivates).

Comment: you can't if you use a ListFragment

Comment: @Funkystein Okay, I didn't know that, so if I extend fragment, then I can use two listviews?

Comment: **YES**. How many you want. This would be the easier and most practical solution.

Answer (score 2):

> What I wonder is how do I refer to two different listviews that are using @android:id/list?

The simple answer is it's not possible (assuming both `ListViews` are in the same layout).

The id `@android:id/list` is simply a 'convenience' way of defining a resource id for a `ListView` when using a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`.

The id of each widget in a layout must be unique which means you should define your own for the `ListViews`.

Answer (score 1):

in your xml file :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         >
    </ListView>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         >
    </ListView>
```

get reference of listview as:

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
```

**Remember :** `R.id.list1` not `android.R.id.list1`

Comment: Yes, then I get this error "must have a listview whos id must be android.R.id.list".

Comment: **"must have a listview whos id must be android.R.id.list"** because you are extending `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`

Comment: @EdoardoMoreni clean and build your project

Answer (score 0):

In your xml define a custom id with: `android:id="@+id/yourId"` and reference the list with this new id

Comment: I can't do it, "must have a listview whos id must be android.R.id.list".

Comment: this answer is wrong. Op is using a ListFragment, and the constraint of ListFragment is that id of the ListView has to be `android.R.id.list`

Comment: **"must have a listview whos id must be android.R.id.list"** because you are extending `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`